# How to get a href parameter value

Tags: struts2, ognl

How to get `val` value?

This is my index.jsp:

```html
<a href="index.jsp?val=admin">Admin</a>
<a href="index.jsp?val=member">Member</a>
<s:set var="v" value="#attr.val"></s:set>
<s:property value="#v"/>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to display?

Comment: val value admin or member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get parameters by using special keyword named... wait for that... `#parameters`.

```html
<s:property value="#parameters.val"/>
```